# Kolmogorov complexity of string concatenation

Tags: computability, kolmogorov-complexity

If $K(s)$ is the [Kolmogorov complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) of the string $s \in \{0,1\}^*$,

> Can we prove (or disprove) the following statement:
>
> "Every string $s$ is a prefix of an incompressible string; i.e. for every string $s$ there exists a string $r$ such that $K(sr) \geq |sr|$" ?

In a very informal (and perhaps not too meaningful) way: we know that $K(r) \leq |r| + O(1)$; if we pick a large enough incompressible string $r$, can we "use" the $O(1)$ to "mask" the compressibility of the given string $s$ ?

A similar (but different) result is that for any $c$, we can find $s$ and $r$ such that: $K(sr) > K(s) + K(r) + c$

Comment: Does incompressible mean that the length of the string $s$ is a lower bound on its shortest description $K(s)$?

Comment: @saadtaame: it means that $K(s) \geq |s|$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conjecture is wrong. For some constants $C,D$, it holds that $K(sr) \leq 2K(s) + K(r) + C \leq 2K(s) + |r| + D$ (proof: use a universal Turing machine to generate $s$ and then $r$; you need somewhat more than $K(s)+K(r)$ to store both programs, though $2K(s)+K(r)$ is an overkill). Therefore if $2K(s) + D < |s|$, your conjecture doesn't hold. Such easy strings $s$ certainly exist, for example $K(0^n) = O(\log n)$.

Comment: it seems ok. I thought that $D$ depends on $r$, but once fixed the UTM it is a constant. Another consideration: in concatenating the two strings one must add $\log |s|$ bits (to delimit the program for $s$ from the program for $r$), so your proof doesn't work if we modify the "conjecture" into: "every *incompressible* string $s$ is a prefix of an incompressible string $r$"? Can you see how to (dis)prove it easily?

Comment: The latter conjecture is less interesting since $s$ is already incompressible. Formally, you could choose $r = s$, though this solution is easy to disallow.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus, do you have any ideas on how to prove the second statement, i.e., for any $c$, we can find $s$ and $r$ such that: $$K(sr)>K(s)+K(r)+c$$ This is stated in Sipser's book and left as an exercise problem, but I was not able to prove it, and I am very curious to know what kind of proof technique should be used to show this result. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you post this as a new question with the 'Ask Question' button.  When you do that, it might help if you told us what approaches you tried.  It definitely doesn't belong as an answer here.

Comment: dear Yuval, +1, but it's not clear to me why we don't have $K(sr)\leqslant K(s)+K(r)+O(1)$. indeed, if we have a program outputting $s$ of length $K(s)$, and one outputting $r$ of length $K(r)$, why can't we just essentially concatenate the two to output $sr$? apologies if this is an extremely naive question; I'm very ignorant in these matters

Comment: Programs are not self-terminating. There is also a version of Kolmogorov complexity for self-terminating programs.

Comment: dear Yuval. thank you, that makes sense! may I ask which is the more standard of the two definitions? for example, which definition does the book by Li and Vitányi employ?

Comment: (I ask because I'm hoping to learn a bit about the subject this summer, and am trying to find the right reference to work through.)

Comment: The book considers both definitions. The more usual one is not self-delimiting.

Comment: many thanks again!